# add pages dynamically to turnjs book

Tags: jquery, turnjs

I need to build a book dynamically. I'm using turnjs.
see this fiddle : [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Lithium/5KbDv/)

here's the function for adding the page:

```
function addContent() {
     var element = '<p>SomeContent</p><a href="#">Go To Page 1</a>';
    var pageCount = $('#flipbook').turn('pages') * 1;
    $('#flipbook').turn('addPage', element, pageCount+1)
    .turn('pages', $('#flipbook').turn('pages'));
}
```

the first problem is that the page is added at the end, first of all I need to control this for adding the page every where I want.

the second problem is that the added page doesn't get the book effects! like it's not the book's page. how can I fix this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your code work probably if you just used the function that sets the
total number of the pages you want to include, other wise the library
gonna delete from the end, all of the extra pages.
in other words this version of your code will work perfectly.

```
function addContent() {
    var pageCount = $('#flipbook').turn('pages')+1 ;
    var possitionOfAddition = 2 ;// this is an example, place the position you want to add the new content , use the var pageCount in case you want to add into last.
    element = $('<div>This is test</div>');
    alert('just befor the addition');
    $('#flipbook').turn('addPage', element,possitionOfAddition);                    
    alert('just after the addition');
    $('#flipbook').turn('pages', pageCount); // Sets the total # of pages
}
```

for the effects I didn't really face that problem, however try using
the 4th version instead of the 3rd.